# RESTful design: Best practices for child resource creation

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Scenario:

I have some resource, `Foo`, which has 0..n child resources, `Bar`.

There is an endpoint- http://resource/foo - which supports `GET` to fetch the list of all `Foo` resources and `POST` to create a new instance of Foo on the parent server.

There is an endpoint- http://resource/foo/:fooId: - which supports `GET` to fetch a `Foo` resource, `PATCH` to update a `Foo` resource, and `DELETE` to delete a `Foo` resource.

There is an endpoint- http://resource/foo/:fooId:/bar - which supports `GET` to fetch the list of all `Bar` resources on a given `Foo`, and `POST` to create a new instance of `Bar` on a given Foo.

Should `POST` to http://resource/foo support creating a `Foo` with some `Bar` children directly, or should child creation only be supported by distinct additional `POSTs` to http://resource/foo/:fooId:/bar after the initial creation of `Foo`?

Comment: Often times, the most logical approach would be have an endpoint like `POST /bars`. The request body would be a representation of the properties required to construct a bar which would include the identifier of the related foo. An endpoint like `/foos/:id/bars` is more of a "shortcut" or filtering endpoint for providing a filtered version of the `/bars` collection, and typically only supports `GET` requests. However, none of what I have said are hard rules; more like good guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately such questions have no common answer, because you need to consider business domain and the environment your api is working on (performance, public availability, standards, the way existing endpoints are designed etc.) and a huge list of other factors. However, it is good to start from business perspective, as any code is intended to solve real-world issues.

You may start with asking youself the following question:

- Does `Foo` (as a real world entity) makes sense without any `Bar` attached?

or something like:

Is `Bar` optional at the moment of creation a `Foo`?

If you see it is optional then leave `Bar` as a subresource and deal with collection/instance of `Bar` independently. Just add Bar as embeded resource using [hal](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for example, that would be very `RESTful` and make parent-child relationship transparent. Keeping resource as simple as possible and less coupled as possible is a good strategy for `REST` api.